# How to wrap a list while preserving content with xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a test file I've been playing with, and I'm trying to wrap the <listitem> element while keeping the rest of the content unchanged. I've been trying to use for-each-group, but it wraps each list item in an <ol>. I can get it to work if I change the template match to the root , but then I lose everything else. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance. Here's the xml and xsl that I have so far.

xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<chapter>
<title toc_id="new">An new story</title>
<para>New stories are different</para>
<listitem class="ol">Here is one list item</listitem>
<listitem class="ol">Here is two list item</listitem>
<listitem class="ol">Here is three list item</listitem>
<section>
<title toc_id="h2-intro-1">Introduction H1</title>
<para>Upon a time ....</para>
<title toc_id="h2-intro-2">Introduction H2</title>
<para>... there was a young prince. http://www.stuff.com, here's a website</para>
</section>
</chapter>
</document>
```

For the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" 
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="listitem">
<xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="@class">
<ol>
<xsl:for-each select=".">
<li>
<p>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</p>
</li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ol>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<document>
<chapter>
<title toc_id="new">An new story</title>
<para>New stories are different</para>
<ol>
<li>
<p>Here is one list item</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Here is two list item</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>Here is three list item</p>
</li>
</ol>
<section>
<title toc_id="h2-intro-1">Introduction H1</title>
<para>Upon a time ....</para>
<title toc_id="h2-intro-2">Introduction H2</title>
<para>... there was a young prince. http://www.stuff.com, here's a website</para>
</section>
</chapter>
</document>
```

Comment: So do you need to wrap adjacent `listitem` elements together or only those having a certain `class` attribute or the same class? Can there be mixed content as well, i.e. non white-space text nodes between element nodes? In general this seems a task on `match="*[listitem]"` and then with `for-each-group group-adjacent="boolean(self::listitem)"` perhaps with a nested `for-each-group group-by="@class"`.

Comment: Nope, I was trying to figure out how to wrap similar elements, and couldn't quite wrap my head around how for-each-group was working.

Answer (score 0):

Because the template for `listitem` matches every single item, and the your `fo-each-group` only applies on `.` (current element) it results in wrapping every element.

You need to tweak more the selection.

Your template need only to apply on `listitem`, whose predecessor is not `listitem` (maybe listitem with same class). Inside the template you need to open the `ol` tag, and then use different rule to ourput the content of the item and all successors as long as they are `listitem`.

Check the XPath axes: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

It should be possible to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="listitem[preceding-sibling::self[position()=1 and name() != 'listitem']]">
    <ol>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inlist" select="."/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="listitem" mode="inlist">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    <xsl:apply-templates  select="following-sibling::self[position() = 1 and name() = 'listitem']" mode="inlist"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I knew there was something wrong with my match! Thanks for explaining what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `match="*[listitem]"` or `match="*[listitem[@class]]"` to match on the parent element containing the `listitem` elements you want to group/wrap and then use `for-each-group` on the children of the parent, if you only expect them to be elements you can use `select="*" composite="yes" group-adjacent="boolean(self::listitem), @class"` in XSLT 3  to identify adjacent `listitem` with the same `class` attribute value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[listitem]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" composite="yes" group-adjacent="boolean(self::listitem), @class">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()[1]">
                      <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()[2]}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </xsl:element>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="listitem">
      <li>
          <p>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </p>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJK

With XSLT 2 you can use two nested `for-each-group` e.g.

```
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::listitem)">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="@class">
                      <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </xsl:element>                          
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
```

see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJK/1, for a full XSLT 2 solution you would of course need to replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template (you already have in your posted code).

Comment: Awesome answer! This has greatly helped me understand what I was missing regarding for-each-group.